# @media query not working with 2 display: none; tags

Tags: html, css, web

I created a website and I used 2 divs, 1 has all the code for the desktop layout and one has all the code for mobile, I did this and would like to keep it this way for future changes,

On both divs display is default and on the media queries I have it set as this:

```
/* DESKTOP AND MOBILE VEIWPORT TOGGLE */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 100vw) {
    .mobile {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="desktop">
    <p>desktop</p>
</div>

<--- MOBILE DIV --->

<div class="mobile">
    <p>mobile</p>
</div>
```

Also, all of my code can be found here with the html
https://codesandbox.io/s/soph2?file=/css/index.css:244-451

Also sorry if this was a stupid question, I'm 13 and I've only been coding for a year now.

When I go to a mobile device, the desktop view does not show but neither does any of my mobile code, please help me, thank you very much!

Also, I just noticed when on the desktop mode, the mobile div shows up too for some reason under the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in the head section :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

```css
 @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
      .desktop {
        display: none;
      }
      .mobile {
        display: block;
      }
    }

      @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
        .mobile {
          display: none;
        }
        .desktop {
          display: block;
        }
      }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="desktop">
  <p>desktop</p>
</div>



<div class="mobile">

  <p>mobile</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the html

Comment: OMG! , ThankYou So Much, i spent so many hours tryin to fix this myself but it didnt work, ThankYou So Much!!! :D

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1):

Media queries never go in media queries. Each one is basically a separate bit of css for a specific screen. In addition, 100vw should never be used in media queries, since it will always match. Also, please try to properly format your code. Makes it much more readable

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok! thanks, ima text this out now, also i will format my code too! :D

Comment: Does the element you're trying to hide have the right class?

Comment: the divs are corret and set the code you send but it no work, u can test your code with the small open in tab on the right side of the search bar in the miniveiw, then ucan change your browser windows size, i get no text on mobile still.

Comment: ok i found the problem but idk how to fix it, idk how but we could use min-width, but idk how, so when the width is 400 it hides the desktop, but at the same time when the desktop is on it hides both, or im saying this backwards , but thats wats happening, could you try helping me with how to add the min width?

Comment: how about you provide all code in a snipet not askign others to correct your code which you not provide directly.

Comment: oki ill send that, thooo its rlly big so for html im only gona send the divs for mobile and desktop with a <p></p> in it